# How to find the cause of a broken wso2mi-dashboard?

Tags: wso2

Good day everyone.
We have wso2 implemented on three Docker containers. Everything worked fine until after adding the next flow, the entrance to the Micro Integration Dashboard stopped working. Moreover, the system itself continues to work, only you can not enter the panel.

Error image

[image: 1]

login failed internal server error

No changes were made to the users or to the container itself.
I've searched and read everything I can, but I can't even grasp where the problem is.
Please push me in the right direction.
Here is the error from the logs:

```
[2023-01-12 07:40:08,602] ERROR {LoginDelegate} - Error logging into dashboard server java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
        at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.delegates.auth.LoginDelegate.getTokenFromMI(LoginDelegate.java:80)
        at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.delegates.auth.LoginDelegate.authenticateUser(LoginDelegate.java:51)
        at org.wso2.ei.dashboard.core.rest.api.LoginApi.receiveLogin(LoginApi.java:56)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1450)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:600)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:555)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:164)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: What is the version you are using?